# pandas rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have below information in pandas dataframe as df,and I'm trying to have code values as column values for each adm_id, and naming columns with their positions.

```
ID  ADM_ID  code
108 183350  7100
108 183350  5849
108 183350  5780
108 183350  99811
108 183350  4466
108 183350  40301
108 183350  58281
108 183350  E8798
108 183350  58889
108 183350  4430
108 183350  78659
109 128755  4372
109 128755  78039
109 128755  7100
109 128755  40391
109 128755  4251
109 128755  2859
109 164029  40301
109 164029  7100
109 164029  5856
109 164029  V4983
109 164029  58381
109 164029  3643
109 108375  7100
109 108375  40301
109 108375  5856
109 108375  58381
109 108375  3643
109 108375  28521
109 193281  40301
109 193281  5856
109 193281  7100
109 193281  7907
109 193281  4254
109 193281  99662
109 193281  99812
109 193281  36001
109 193281  11289
109 193281  V5865
109 193281  7821
109 193281  28521
109 193281  37900
109 193281  37632
109 193281  37005
109 193281  36400
```

I want this to be converted as below,

```
ID  ADM_ID  cnt code1   code2   code3   code4   code5   code6   code7   code8   code9   code10  code11  code12  code13  code14  code15  code16
108 183350  11  7100    5849    5780    99811   4466    40301   58281   E8798   58889   4430    78659                   
109 128755  6   4372    78039   7100    40391   4251    2859                                        
109 164029  6   40301   7100    5856    V4983   58381   3643                                        
109 108375  6   7100    40301   5856    58381   3643    28521                                       
109 193281  16  40301   5856    7100    7907    4254    99662   99812   36001   11289   V5865   7821    28521   37900   37632   37005   36400
```

I can't promise that codes will have only 16, each id will have random number of codes. Can somebody please help me to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but i think [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) should prove useful

Answer (score 0):

On what basis are datum being assigned to the columns? From the data you posted it is unclear on what basis the data is being assigned to the new columns.

It seems like the .pivot() function would work well here. However you need to add some key or .groupby() argument to reshape the dataframe.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Update:

First pass a groupby arguement -

```
new_df = old_df.groupby('admin_id')
```

Then pass a pivot argument -

```
newer_df = new_dt.pivot('code')
```

Comment: i'm trying to have code values as column values for each adm_id, Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup, now I've got a better idea of what you want. Try the code I posted above and see if that works -- check out the documentation too as these are useful functions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `list` from values of `code` column
- create `Series` `l` for new columns names and for `cnt` column
- [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor from values of `df`
- [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) for new column names and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
- last [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column as `3.` column (`2`, because python counts from 0)

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','ADM_ID'])['code'].apply(list)
l = df1.str.len()

df = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist(), 
                  index=df1.index, 
                  columns = range(1, l.max() +1)) \
       .add_prefix('code') \
       .reset_index()

df.insert(2, 'cnt', l.values)
print (df)
    ID  ADM_ID  cnt  code1  code2 code3  code4  code5  code6  code7  code8  \
0  108  183350   11   7100   5849  5780  99811   4466  40301  58281  E8798   
1  109  108375    6   7100  40301  5856  58381   3643  28521   None   None   
2  109  128755    6   4372  78039  7100  40391   4251   2859   None   None   
3  109  164029    6  40301   7100  5856  V4983  58381   3643   None   None   
4  109  193281   16  40301   5856  7100   7907   4254  99662  99812  36001   

   code9 code10 code11 code12 code13 code14 code15  code16  
0  58889   4430  78659   None   None   None   None    None  
1   None   None   None   None   None   None   None    None  
2   None   None   None   None   None   None   None    None  
3   None   None   None   None   None   None   None    None  
4  11289  V5865   7821  28521  37900  37632  37005  36400
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

It might be helpful to do this with `groupby`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'ADM_ID'])['code'].agg([np.count_nonzero,
                                                lambda x: tuple(x)])
df3 = pd.concat([df2.reset_index(),
                 pd.DataFrame(df2['<lambda>'].tolist())],
                axis=1)
del df3['<lambda>']
cols = ['ID', 'ADM_ID', 'cnt']
cols.extend(['code'+str(i) for i in range(1, len(df3.columns)-2)])
df3.columns = cols
df3
Out[52]: 
    ID  ADM_ID  cnt  code1  code2 code3  code4  code5  code6  code7  code8  \
0  108  183350   11   7100   5849  5780  99811   4466  40301  58281  E8798   
1  109  108375    6   7100  40301  5856  58381   3643  28521   None   None   
2  109  128755    6   4372  78039  7100  40391   4251   2859   None   None   
3  109  164029    6  40301   7100  5856  V4983  58381   3643   None   None   
4  109  193281   16  40301   5856  7100   7907   4254  99662  99812  36001   

   code9 code10 code11 code12 code13 code14 code15 code16  
0  58889   4430  78659   None   None   None   None   None  
1   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None  
2   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None  
3   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None  
4  11289  V5865   7821  28521  37900  37632  37005  36400
```

### **Edit: Method 2**

If you can get fully numeric codes, which I only mention because you seem so close, then you could instead use `pivot` and `np.sort`:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='ADM_ID', columns='code', values='code')
df2.values.sort()
df2.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.columns = ['code'+str(i) for i in range(1, len(df2.columns)+1)]
df2.insert(0, 'cnt', df2.count(axis=1))
df2
Out[71]: 
        cnt   code1   code2   code3    code4    code5    code6    code7  \
ADM_ID                                                                    
108375    6  3643.0  5856.0  7100.0  28521.0  40301.0  58381.0      NaN   
128755    6  2859.0  4251.0  4372.0   7100.0  40391.0  78039.0      NaN   
164029    6  3643.0  4983.0  5856.0   7100.0  40301.0  58381.0      NaN   
183350   11  4430.0  4466.0  5780.0   5849.0   7100.0   8798.0  40301.0   
193281   16  4254.0  5856.0  5865.0   7100.0   7821.0   7907.0  11289.0   

          code8    code9   code10   code11   code12   code13   code14  \
ADM_ID                                                                  
108375      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
128755      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
164029      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
183350  58281.0  58889.0  78659.0  99811.0      NaN      NaN      NaN   
193281  28521.0  36001.0  36400.0  37005.0  37632.0  37900.0  40301.0   

         code15   code16  
ADM_ID                    
108375      NaN      NaN  
128755      NaN      NaN  
164029      NaN      NaN  
183350      NaN      NaN  
193281  99662.0  99812.0
```

Which is a bit faster on this data with the `E`s and `V`s stripped (2.63 ms vs 4.84 ms for me), and around twelve times faster (5.92 ms vs 74.2 ms) when tested on a dataframe with the same number of adm_ids and 100 times as many codes.

Unfortunately, `sort` for numpy arrays doesn't seem to play nicely with `NaN`s in string arrays, and any workarounds I've noticed there seem to be costlier than groupby.

Answer (score 0):

Use method chaining to do this in one go. First groupby 'ID' and 'ADM_ID', then convert group values and count into a list, next convert the list to columns, adding prefix, renaming count column name and finally reset index.

This solution will handle more or less columns automatically.

```
(df.groupby(['ID','ADM_ID'])
    .apply(lambda x: [len(x)]+x.code.tolist())
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .add_prefix('code')
    .rename(columns={'code0':'cnt'})
    .reset_index()
)

Out[389]: 
    ID  ADM_ID  cnt  code1  code2 code3  code4  code5  code6  code7  code8  \
0  108  183350   11   7100   5849  5780  99811   4466  40301  58281  E8798   
1  109  108375    6   7100  40301  5856  58381   3643  28521    NaN    NaN   
2  109  128755    6   4372  78039  7100  40391   4251   2859    NaN    NaN   
3  109  164029    6  40301   7100  5856  V4983  58381   3643    NaN    NaN   
4  109  193281   16  40301   5856  7100   7907   4254  99662  99812  36001   

   code9 code10 code11 code12 code13 code14 code15 code16  
0  58889   4430  78659    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
4  11289  V5865   7821  28521  37900  37632  37005  36400
```